# tf.gradients() return None

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement [integratedGradients](https://github.com/hiranumn/IntegratedGradientsTF) on a toy example. The generated data and placeholders are defined as follows:

```
x_pure = np.random.randint(-10,10,[10, 227, 227, 11])
y_test = np.sum(x_pure**2,axis=(1,2,3))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='x_input', shape=[None, 227, 227, 11])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='y_input', shape=[None,1])
```

The corruption occurs in this function:

```
res = ig.build_ig(inter, stepsize, pred, num_steps=50)
# INPUT: samples: linearly interpolated samples between input samples and references. output of linear_interpolation()
#        stepsizse: output of linear_interpolation()
#        _output: output tensor to be explained. It needs to be connected to samples.
# OUTPUT: explanations: A list of tensors with explanation values. 

def build_ig(samples, stepsizes, _output, num_steps=50):
    grads = tf.gradients(ys=_output, xs=samples)
```

In debugger:

```
_output=Tensor("Sum:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32)
samples=Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(?, 227, 227, 11), dtype=float32)
grads=<class 'list'>: [None]
```

Since the `tf.gradients()` function returns None, the next operation cannot be performed. Where should I even start to look for fixing this error?

Comment: You get `None` gradients when the requested gradients could not be computed. This may happen because: a) `_output` (`pred`) does not depend on `samples` (`inter`), that is, does not use it in its computation or b) there is a dependency between the tensors, but you have used some non-differentiable operation (e.g. argmax). Without a complete minimal reproducible example it's impossible to tell what exactly is the problem.

Comment: `pred` is computed as `pred = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(x, 2),[1,2,3])`. I cannot tell out which operation isn't differentiable...

Comment: Those operations are differentiable, but how is `inter` related to `pred`?

Comment: `inter` is returned from the `linear_interpolation(sample, num_steps=50)` function.  `x` is passed as the input argument. This function linearly interpolates `x` and output a tensor which has the same shape as `x`. Then execute `ig.build_ig(inter, stepsize, pred, num_steps=50)`. The definition of `ig.build_ig(...)` is partially displayed above.

Comment: It sounds like both `pred` and `inter` are computed from `x`, but `pred` is not computed from `inter`. To put it in another way, if you want to compute that gradient, `inter` must be a necessary step in the computation of `pred`. But it sounds like you can compute `pred` without "passing through" `inter`, right? Then, the operations are not connected in the graph and no gradient can be computed.

Comment: That’s exactly where the problem is! It 's very kind of you to help.